# How to connect other PCs to my DUMeter.net account in DU Meter?

Tags: windows-10, du-meter

I am trying to get my 3 PCs connected to my DUMeter.net account in DU Meter, and during configuring it I get the message: "The code above must be copied into DU Meter client software in order to establish a link between your computer and your dumeter.net account".

Where do I go to on the other two PCs to enter the code?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click DU-Meter, choose "Welcome wizard...", and go through the wizard again:

[image: DUMeter R-click]

On the third or fourth page you can add the DUMeter.net "computer code":

[image: Computer Code page]

Comment: No it does not work! I've tried it again and the window does not come up! One has to uninstall all the software and then reinstall and then use the code previously delivered - then it works fine! But thanks for your help!